# How do I sort pivot chart groups by their actual value, not their stringified group name?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

When I group by a date field, it formats the grouped field as a string and then sorts the recordset as a string rather than its actual value (see screenshots). When grouping by day, it turns 8/10/2021 into 10-Aug. Setting the formatting of the column doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I preserve the original value/data type being grouped by?

This is for Excel 2007 (just want to reiterate that).

Edit: When I create a pivot table from the same data, the grouping behaves as expected (sorts by the date value, not the stringified format).

[image: screenshot 1]           [image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about grouping by Months and Days? And then add the Month field to Rows as a workaround?

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks for that solution. I think it's probably just an old Office bug because it doesn't exhibit this behavior with regular pivot tables. Another thing is that, when I remove the month from the grouping, the days are ordered properly. Weird. Edit: I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep.